# Prioritize Autowiring of bean when there are multiple implementations

Tags: java, spring

I have a service class XYZ.java that is Autowired in some other class ABC.java. I want to extend the service class XYZ and want to override some methods of this class.

Now, As i can not change ABC.java impl but want that when method of Autowired class is called then
i should call overriden method. How can i do that??

```
@Service
class XYZ {
    public void m1(){
    }
}

@Service
Class ABC{
    @Autowired
    XYZ xyz;

    public void m2(){
       xyz.m1();
    }
}

Here i want to extend XYZ class

@Service
class XYZExtended extends XYZ{
  @Override
  public void m1(){
  } 
}
```

I want that when ABC.m2() is called it should call  XYZExtended.m1() method.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just remove `@Service` from `XYZ`.

Comment: @Unmitigated, Thanks for the response.  I can not modify XYZ class.

Comment: Why not Autowire `XYZExtended` then?

Comment: @Unmitigated, glitch here is class XYZ and ABC can not be modified as these two are available in jar that is coming from product team.

Comment: Making a component as primary solve the issue... use @Primary